# Python Project - ImportError: No module named XXX?

Tags: python

I am building a python project, where I have currently 2 modules `dr` and `mg`.

I have done **exactly the same thing** to these two modules, but `dr` can be imported in `main.py`, whereas `mg` cannot.

```
>>> from mg import visualization as vl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mg
>>> from dr import simulation as sm
>>>
```

I **have added both** `dr` and `mg` folders into the `PYTHONPATH` as seen from the small green plus sign there on the folder names.

[image]

Where goes wrong?

Comment: What's in mg/__init__.py?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but don't you have to do `import mg.visualization as vl`?

Comment: Try remove `__init__.py` from `mg`

Comment: @Haidro No, import `mg.visualization as vl` can work. See `dr` import

Comment: @J0HN my point exactly

Comment: "I have added both dr and mg folders into the PYTHONPATH" Wait! You should **not** do this. Since `mg` and `dr` are packages you should add their *parent* folder in the PYTHONPATH, i.e. the `traclus` folder in your example. Also, try to do `import os; print(os.getcwd())` in your python console to check in which directory you are running that code.

Comment: @J0HN a '#'. It is created automatically by the IDE

Comment: @Bakuriu  awesome! cool! this is the solution. May I suggest you to put it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have added both `dr` and `mg` folders into the `PYTHONPATH`

Wait! You should *not* do this. Since `mg` and `dr` are packages you should add their *parent* folder to the `PYTHONPATH`, i.e. the `traclus` folder in your example.

When python looks for a package `a`, it will look at all the directories in the `PYTHONPATH` for a directory called `a` that contains an `__init__.py` file.
If you add the `a` directory to the `PYTHONPATH`, the interpreter will see the `__init__.py`, but it wont know that it is part of a package.

Answer (score 0):

It more comment then answer, but comments can't formatting. I think, problem in your `mg/__init__.py`. Below I try simulate your problem. And all work fine:

```
$ tree -sv
.
├── [       4096]  dr
│   ├── [          0]  __init__.py
│   └── [         25]  simulation.py
├── [         97]  main.py
└── [       4096]  mg
    ├── [          0]  __init__.py
    └── [         28]  visualization.py

2 directories, 5 files    
$ cat mg/visualization.py
print "visualization module"
$ cat dr/simulation.py
print "simulation module"
$ cat main.py
from mg import visualization as vl
from dr import simulation as sm

print dir(vl)
print dir(sm)
$ python main.py 
visualization module
simulation module
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```